# What are the odds of receiving each "blessing" given by the statue?

Tags: rogue-legacy

Once in a while you find a statue that asks if you will pray for it's blessing. 4/5 times I've gotten the Hedgehog's Curse, and as much as I like Sonic, this is so far the only "blessing" I've noticed to be bad.

Is each blessing given out with an equal chance or does the curse have a higher chance to appear from this statue?

Comment: From my experience, you get the curse more often than the others. However, I have yet to come across anybody who has calculated the percentages.

Comment: I believe it depends on your character stats. With a colorblind or near-sighted heir I usually get the glasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I daresay it's all just Random Number Generator magic, making the odds of each curse/blessing a 1/x, with x being the number of blessings. Truth be told, I myself had the glasses more on characters without vision impairments than those with.